# Simplify convoluted $\text{prime}^*$ numbers sum formulae

Tags: prime-numbers, zeta-functions, pseudoprimes

The below is part of a formula I devised to calculate the **sum of the squared reciprocals of all primes and pseudo-primes** (pseudo according to Fermat's Little theorem.)

However, the 4 sums are very convoluted, if I could eliminate the sum over at least one of the indexes I would be happy about the final result, plus it would make computation much easier. That is, I want to collapse at least one of the sums over $i,j,k$ or $p$. But it's so difficult that I threw the towel. Perhaps one of you can. There's another part but it's much simpler.

Btw, I also need help calculating these sums to ensure I didn't make any mistake. Here $m=\log{2}$. On my computer it's taking too long.

For context, these 4 formulae correspond to the last sub-sum ($\sum_{}2^{p n}/n^{2j+2}$) in the equation below (*where $n$ prime also means pseudo-prime, excluding 1*):

> \begin{multline}
> \sum _{n\text{ prime}}^{}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}\sum _{p=1}^{2k} \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{p n}}{n^3}+\\
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum _{p=1}^{2k} \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2^{p n}}{n^{2j+2}}
> \end{multline}

The formulae are based on an analytic continuation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{mp n}/n^{2j+2}$ for $m>0$ -- the sum is obviously finite if $m<0$:

And these are the sums I need simplified (**I'm not sure if the below really converges** due to being an analytical continuation for positive $m=\log{2}$, but I have an alternative to that anyway, if it doesn't):

1:

> \begin{multline}
> -\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum _{p=1}^{2k}
> \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\frac{(m p)^{2 j+1}\text{Log}\left[\frac{m p}{2\pi }\right]}{(2 j+1)!}
> \end{multline}

2:

> \begin{multline}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum _{p=1}^{2k}
> \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\sum _{i=0}^{j+1} \frac{(m p)^{2j+2-2i}\text{Zeta}[2i]}{(2j+2-2i)!}+\sum _{i=1}^j \frac{(m p)^{2j+1-2i}\text{Zeta}[2i+1]}{(2j+1-2i)!}
> \end{multline}

3:

> \begin{multline}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum _{p=1}^{2k}
> \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\sum _{i=1}^j \frac{(m p)^{2j+1-2i}\text{Zeta}[2i+1]}{(2j+1-2i)!}
> \end{multline}

4:

> \begin{multline}
> -\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=0}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum
> _{p=1}^{2k} \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\\
> \frac{(m p)^{2 j+2}}{(2 j+1)!}\int _0^1 \left((1-u)^{2j+1}\text{Coth}\left[\frac{m p u}{2}\right]-\frac{2\pi }{m p} (1-u)
> \text{Cot}[\pi  u]\right)du
> \end{multline}

**And to make things more interesting**, if $x\geq 2$ then $\pi^*(x)$ (*i.e., including pseudo-primes*) is given by:

> \begin{multline}
> \pi^*(x)=2+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } (-1)^k(2\pi )^{2k}(2k)!\sum _{j=1}^k \frac{\text{BernoulliB}[2j]}{(2k+1-2j)!(2j)!}\sum _{p=1}^{2k} \frac{(-2)^{2k-p}}{p!(2k-p)!}\sum
> _{n=1}^x \frac{2^{p n}}{n^{2j}}
> \end{multline}

Again, I'd be able to replace the sum over $n$ with formulae, but it'd not be simple and elegant, too many indexes to sum over.

**Now, back to the original question, this will only be solved if there's some genius reading.** Mathematica's input formulae if you wanna try:

1:

```
    x1 = -Sum[(-1)^k*(2*Pi)^(2*k)*(2*k)!*Sum[(BernoulliB[2*j]/((2*k + 1 - 2*j)!*(2*j)!*(2*j + 1)!))*Sum[(((-2)^(2*k - p)*(m*p)^(2*j + 1))/(p!*(2*k - p)!))*Log[(m*p)/(2*Pi)], {p, 1, 2*k}], {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, M}]
```

2:

```
    x2 = Sum[(-1)^k*(2*Pi)^(2*k)*(2*k)!*Sum[(BernoulliB[2*j]/((2*k + 1 - 2*j)!*(2*j)!))*Sum[((-2)^(2*k - p)/(p!*(2*k - p)!))*Sum[((m*p)^(2*j + 2 - 2*i)*Zeta[2*i])/(2*j + 2 - 2*i)!, {i, 0,j + 1}],{p, 1, 2*k}], {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, M}]
```

3:

```
    x3 = Sum[(-1)^k*(2*Pi)^(2*k)*(2*k)!*Sum[(BernoulliB[2*j]/((2*k + 1 - 2*j)!*(2*j)!))*Sum[((-2)^(2*k - p)/(p!*(2*k - p)!))*Sum[((m*p)^(2*j + 1 - 2*i)*Zeta[2*i + 1])/(2*j + 1 - 2*i)!, {i, 1, j}],{p, 1, 2*k}], {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, M}]
```

4:

```
    x4 = (-(1/2))*Sum[(-1)^k*(2*Pi)^(2*k)*(2*k)!*Sum[(BernoulliB[2*j]/((2*k + 1 - 2*j)!*(2*j)!*(2*j + 1)!))*Sum[(((-2)^(2*k - p)*(m*p)^(2*j + 2))/(p!*(2*k - p)!))*Integrate[(1 - u)^(2*j + 1)*Coth[(m*p*u)/2] -((2*Pi)/(m*p))*(1 - u)*Cot[Pi*u], {u, 0,1}], {p, 1, 2*k}], {j, 0, k}], {k, 1, M}]
```

Comment: @reuns Let me add the context as an edit in the original post.

Comment: @reuns Done, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please exchange $p,n$, in number theory $\sum_p$ means sum over primes.
$\sum_p p^{-2} =  \sum_{k =1}^\infty \frac{ \mu(k) }{k}\log \zeta(2k)= \sum_{k =1}^\infty \frac{ \mu(k) }{k}
\log((-1)^{k+1}\frac{B_{2k}(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}) $. How did you come with your first formula. The other way to make Bernouilli numbers appear are in things like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx} =\sum Res(\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) x^{-s})=x^{-1}+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{(-1)^k B_{k+1}}{k+1} x^k$

Comment: @reuns Good point, however my sum is not over primes only, but also pseudo-primes

Comment: @reuns If you use the indicator function $k$ divides $y$ (it's given by a sum of cosines; but here you make $k=n$ and $y=2^n-2$, Fermat's little theorem implies it will be 1 for prime/pseudo-prime, and 0 otherwise), and sum the result by using Faulhaber's formula, you get the expression at the very bottom ($\pi^*(x)$). A little modification gives you the squared-reciprocals.

Comment: @reuns However, I just had a better idea, to not end up with those ugly sums over various indexes. The catch is that I'm trying to leverage the formula I discovered, the second one at the top.

Comment: @reuns I don't want to interact with someone negative like you, so feel free to skip my posts and whatever. I don't need your insights. Have a good day.

Comment: Well it doesn't make any sense. For sure you want to be capable to explain how you got a given formula. If you goal is to look at $\sum_{n \in C} n^{-2}$ where $C = \{ n \ge 1, \forall a, gcd(n,a)=1 \implies a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \bmod n\}$ then the indicator function of $C$ will be complicated as it will be $1_{n \in C}  = \prod_{a=1, gcd(a,n)=1}^n 1_{n | a^{n-1}-1}$. How do you manipulate and simplify $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2} 1_{n \in C}$.

Comment: @reuns Let's do a deal? Once I finish the paper I'm writing I will post it here for your appreciation, and perhaps you'll understand and see that it does make sense. Right now what I'm trying to do hasn't been achieved yet, but, there are some incredible new formulae that I'm trying to take advantage of. I've done things at times that I thought weren't possible, so wait and see. For the time being, I'm not taking any more suggestions, I'm coming up with other creative ways to do what I want to do. Hope that settles your bitterness and impoliteness for now. Ciao.

Comment: Also for $x > 0$ and $k\ge 0$ integer the Mellin transform and residue theorem gives $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-c} e^{-nx} = \sum Res(\zeta(k+s) \Gamma(s)x^{-s}) = \sum_{m=0, m \ne k-1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} x^m \zeta(k-m) + c_k x^{k-1}$ where $c_k = Res(\zeta(k+s) \Gamma(s),s=1-k)$, the obtained series stays analytic for $0 <|x| < 2\pi$ providing the analytic continuation of the LHS

Comment: @reuns Are you a professor, a graduate student or just an enthusiast? Credentials?

Comment: @reuns My credentials: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11305 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06885